# Chess Atomic Openings

Tags: opening, learning, chess-variants, atomic-chess

I'm studying Atomic Chess. Where can I find openings at? I've found the site [Vlasov's Atomic-Chess Homepage](https://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/%7Echess/atomic/) so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could explore the lichess database of atomic chess games here: https://lichess.org/analysis/atomic

It can be filtered by time control and player’s rating, shows numbers of games played and result percentages per position, and enables an analysis with a stockfish-variant engine.

Lichess is free and open-source.